# Get the data from a string between double quotes in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string with double quotes inside.

EG:

```
<cosmtio :ff "intermit"ksks>
```

I need the data between the `""`

I have tried the `regexp_substr` but still couldn't get the value between double-quotes.

Comment: Please post the sample data.

Comment: <cosmtio :ff "intermit"ksks>

Comment: expecting - intermit

Comment: You may use a simple 1-step solution. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58100236/3832970)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
SELECT
    string,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(string, '.*"([^"]+)".*', '\1') AS quoted_term
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '<cosmtio :ff "intermit"ksks>' AS string FROM dual
)
```

### Demo

Another option, using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT
    string,
    TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '".*"'))
FROM yourTable;
```

But this approach requires nesting two function calls, which means it might not outperform the `REGEXP_REPLACE` version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('<cosmtio :ff "intermit"ksks>', '"([^"]+)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Result FROM DUAL
```

[image]

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/PIFMA48169).

The regex is simple: `"([^"]+)"` matches `"`, then captures any 1+ chars other than `"` into Group 1 and then matches `"`. The last argument is `1` telling Oracle `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to return the Group 1 values. The first (`position`) and the second (`occurrence`) arguments are default, `1`. `NULL` means no specific options need to be passed to the regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('<cosmtio :ff "intermit"ksks>', '^[^"]*("([^"]*)")?.*', '\2') FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with `regexp_substr` as following:

```
Select 
  regexp_substr('<cosmtio :ff "intermit"ksks>', '[^"]+', 1, 2) 
from dual;
```

Cheers!!